# How to destroy activity and reload it again android

Tags: android, listview, lifecycle

Hi I'd like to destroy  the current activity which contains a listview and open up another activity on button click   but then id like to go back and restart that activity and retreive its content ,any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

To start it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

To destroy activity just use `finish();` anywhere you want to destroy it.

EX: add it after `startActivity(i);`

Comment: but the content of the first activity is not restored i.e the listview

Comment: You mean want to save the `ListView` content even if the activity destroyed?

Comment: yes and on return id like to see the listview currently it's just showing me blank when i return to it no data

Comment: Where you get data from?!

Comment: Mysql database using php so i have showlist() method which contains the list and also a getdata method which does the async task

Comment: So you must run the `task` every time activity starts! Just execute the task in `onCreate();`

Answer (score 0):

On FirstActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondeActivity.class));
finish(); // this will destroy current activity
```

On SecondeActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
```

Comment: but the content of the first activity is not restored i.e the listview

Comment: when you call finish() you will destroy activity and when you call startActivity it will call onCreate->onResume->onStart. So you need to restore your data on one of these methods.

Comment: why you destroy first activity with listview anyway? You should keep it and return to them with calling finish() in seconde activity.

Comment: Yes exactly ,and how will i go about doing that ?

Comment: i tried that but it's showing me a blank list no data

Answer (score 0):

To reload your activity:

```
activity.finish();
activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activity.getClass());
activity.startActivity(intent);
```